# How to add new network interface permanent

Tags: centos

How to add new network interface permanent
I use virtualbox running centos 6, I create a new `eth1` network interface, but after I reboot machine then it's gone.. how to add it auto add when boot the machine

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.56.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Comment: If you want to add a new interface for your vm(for eg:eth1), add a new config file ifcfg-eth1 with the ip address. Then go to the virt manager and shutdown the vm and delete only the vm not the volume. use the same volume and create a vm adding a new network hardware. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use command

```
# nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname etho con-name name autoconnect yes ip4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cidr ipv4.gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ipv4.dns xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And then

```
# nmcli connection up name
```

Or you can use gui based too

```
# nmtui
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=no
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=yes
NAME=eth1
IPADDR=192.168.56.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```